# How can i add Header with (Name and value)in string using IBM MQ

Tags: java, header, jvm, ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ V7 API for passing message in message queue. Currently we are passing only body using IBM MQ .now I have to pass Name and value in header before loading in queue.
I checked in many place the solution they provide using JMS api message.setStringProperty(Name,value).

Please check my code (smilar to write() function) in below url. https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/endrasenn.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/readwrite-to-ibm-mq-sample-java-code/amp/

Comment: Thanks for reply joshmc

Comment: Thanks for reply joshmc. Please find my code. MQMessage msg = New MQMessage(); I have created dynamic object now when I am trying to get method setStringProperty(name,value) it's not available. I am using com.ibm.mq jar. Please provide me code for passing value in header before loading in Message queue

Comment: Com.IBM.mq.jar version 7.5

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different MQ APIs available for coding Java applications:

- IBM MQ for classes for Java
- IBM MQ for classes for JMS

Both of them (MQ V7 or higher) support adding a name/value pair as a property.  And yes, the property does go in the USR folder of the MQRFH2 header.

But you should not think in terms of header and payload data.  Don't worry yourself on how MQ handles it but think in terms of name/value properties and payload data.

---

Updated: Oct 3rd, 2017.

First, go read the methods of [MQMessage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMessage.html) class.  There are 26 set***Property methods.  It is very straightforward if you read the MQ docs.

```
MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
sendmsg.setStringProperty("test", "value");
```

Comment: We are using IBM MQ Classes using Java. Could you please provide a snippet for that. It will be really helpful.